Is there a way of converting JavaScript to jquery for onclick functions
Iam using framework 7 and have been trying to embed JavaScript chat script by converting to jquery the problem is that framework 7 does not accept on click function in pure JavaScript
<div class="uRow" id="usr<?=$uid?>" onclick="msg.show(<?=$uid?>)">
        <div class="uName"><?=$u["user_name"]?></div>
        <div class="uUnread"><?=isset($u["unread"])?$u["unread"]:0?></div>
</div>

It shows this error = msg not defined, So what i have been trying to do is to convert the entire javascript code to jquery
So my problem is to change this div class function to jquery function and make it to match the jquery code .
So I have try to use this method I found on the internet
<div id="myDiv">Some Content</div>
$('#myDiv').click(divFunction);
function divFunction(){
 //some code
}

but get stuck on how to include the  php values
to jquery but cannot figure how to go on about it. I am in need of assistance please
Here is my script
var msg = {

  // (B) SHOW MESSAGES
  
  uid : null,  // current selected user
  show : uid => {
    // (B1) SET SELECTED USER ID
    msg.uid = uid;

    // (B2) GET HTML ELEMENTS
    let hForm = document.getElementById("uSend"),
        hTxt = document.getElementById("mTxt"),
        hUnread = document.querySelector(`#usr${uid} .uUnread`),
        hMsg = document.getElementById("uMsg");

    // (B3) SET SELECTED USER
    for (let r of document.querySelectorAll(".uRow")) {
      if (r.id=="usr"+uid) { r.classList.add("now"); }
      else { r.classList.remove("now"); }
    }
  },
  
};


This is an X/Y problem. You need to use the events as descripbed in the documentation. And you certainly do not want to use jQuery

Also document.querySelectorAll(".uRow").forEach(row => row.classList.toggle('now',row.id=== \usr${uid}`))`

jquery is made of javascript. how does the final html look like?

How does a $uid look like? you might be breaking the javascript if the value isn't surrounded by quotes. Also, if data comes from user it might contain XSS attack.
This is a more correct way to output into HTML and into an attribute:
<?php
function esc_attr($str)
{
    return htmlspecialchars((string) $str, ENT_QUOTES);
}

function stringify($obj)
{
    return json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}

$u = [
    "user_name" => "hello<script>alert(2)</script>",
];
$uid = "82736412212423456";
?>

<div class="uRow" id="usr<?php echo esc_attr($uid); ?>" onclick="msg.show(<?php echo esc_attr(stringify($uid)); ?>)">
    <div class="uName"><?php echo esc_attr($u["user_name"]); ?></div>
    <div class="uUnread"><?php echo esc_attr(isset($u["unread"]) ? $u["unread"] : 0); ?></div>
</div>

As for the javascript - should work better than jQuery - you can use element.addEventListener('click', function(ev) { ... })
